# Problem with Scipy_JupyterNotebook (module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'info')

Tags: python, scipy

I've got a question for you: I'm trying to work on a dataset on excel using jupyter notebook. The problem is that i can't do anything with scipy for some reason... (I've already done some operation before and there were no problem, although I had to uninstall and reinstall jupyter).
Here it is the issue:

> > import scipy
> >     scipy.stats
> >
> > from scipy import stats, optimize, interpolate
> >     scipy.**version**
> >     '1.4.1'
> >
> > scipy.**file**'
> >     C:\Users\Megaport\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py'
> >
> > stats.info()

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  ----> 1 stats.info() AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'info'

Comment: scipy's `stats` does not have an `info()` method.  Try this (after `from scipy import stats`): `stats.zscore([1, 2, 3])`.  Do you get an array as the result?

Comment: Yes I get 

array([-1.22474487,  0.        ,  1.22474487])

Comment: Victory!  This means the `scipy.stats` module works.

Comment: Ok, but my problem still persist....i don't know how to operate in this situation
The last time i was using a csv file and following a tutorial that used stats.info, stats.head ecc.... Now i don't know how to proceed

Comment: Could you share the link to the tutorial?

Comment: It's on udemy, it's a course for python...
the only difference was that the file given was a .csv (mine it's a xlsx)
so the operation were:
pd.read_csv('''')

Comment: nope because i bought the crouse, you wouldn't see the video!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up things here the methods you refer to are available when using pandas DataFrames see this [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)

You can use the 'info' and 'head' method as you describe in your comment above when dealing with pandas df's

The stats module has a 'describe' method but does not have an 'info' method.

You can check the official scipy documentation here [scipy.stats.describe](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.describe.html)